# DeleteZero's using Java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to finish this code which involves deleting all the zero's stored in the array. I thought it was complete but it won't compile, it's my last line that is dubios and I'm not getting right. Thank you.

```
public class DeleteZero {

  public static int[] array(int[] a) {    
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (a[i] !=0)
      k++;
    }

    int[] b = new int[k];

    int t = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (a[i] != 0) {
        b[t] = a[i];
        t++;
      }
    }

    return b;
  }

  public static void main (String args[]) {      
    int[] rand = new int[20];

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      rand[i] = (int)(Math.random());
    }      
    System.out.println(array(a));
  }    
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `array(rand)` instead of `array(a)`?

Comment: Also you want `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array(rand)));` as the default toString() for arrays is not what most people would want.

Comment: What is the "a" variable in System.out.println(array(a));?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few errors.

This would always insert 0 at rand[i] because you are casting Math.random() to int which will always become zero.

```
  rand[i] = (int)(Math.random());
```

Change it to sth like this. I have written 10 but you can write any number to define the range.

```
  rand[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
```

This line is also wrong:

```
System.out.println(array(a));
```

You need to print the array by looping over it, but more importantly your function array() returns a new array, which should be stored somewhere before printing it.

Here is a possible workaround

```
rand = array(rand);
 for (int i=0; i<rand.length; i++){
     System.out.println(rand[i]);
 }
```

Comment: No need to loop to print the array, that is what `Arrays.toString()` is for.

Comment: Thank you! I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

The compile time error is due to the fact that, in the main method you have created the array named `rand` and passing the array named `a`. from the main method call `System.out.print(array(rand))`

Answer (score -1):

You can try Java 8's Stream, which turns the whole logic to one line `return Arrays.stream(a).filter(n -> n!= 0).toArray();`

Comment: Although a valid alternative, this doesn't in any way address the problem posed in the question, i.e. the incorrect call to the `array` method. The question is not about the implementation of the `array` method.

Answer (score -1):

Little fixed your code:

```
import java.util.Random; // Import Random
public class DeleteZero {

    public static int[] array(int[] a) {
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] !=0)
                k++;
        }
        int[] b = new int[k];
        int t = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] != 0) {
                b[t] = a[i];
                t++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Skip at position: [" + i + "] because a[i] == "+a[i]+";"); // Display what removed.
            }
        }
        return b;
    } 

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int[] rand = new int[20];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            rand[i] = rnd.nextInt(11) + 0; // 11-1 = max, 0 = min
        }
        int[] a = array(rand);
        System.out.println(a); // since it prints something like this: [I@106d69c, we should print all elements manually through a loop.
        System.out.println("a.length = " + a.length + ", rand length: " + rand.length);
        System.out.print("[");
        for (int i = 0; i != a.length; i++) {
            String space = ", ";
            if (i == a.length-1) //if last not print space
                space = "";
            System.out.print(a[i]+space); // Print all elements
        }
        System.out.print("]\n");
    }
}
```

Example of output:

```
Skip at position: [2] because a[i] == 0;
Skip at position: [8] because a[i] == 0;
Skip at position: [10] because a[i] == 0;
Skip at position: [12] because a[i] == 0;
Skip at position: [16] because a[i] == 0;
[I@106d69c
a.length = 15, rand length: 20
[6, 8, 1, 8, 7, 1, 3, 5, 3, 8, 5, 2, 7, 2, 8]
```

Comment: No need to loop to print the array, that is what `Arrays.toString()` is for.

Comment: `rnd.nextInt(10) + 0` means max is 9, not 10.